# Is C# pattern matching bettern than polymorphism?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, pattern-matching

C# 7 introduced pattern matching which allows, for example, to switch on types and act according to the underlying type.

Now, and based on the fact that C# is object-oriented the types that we switch on can, for example, implement a same base class or interface and override this base behaviour to achieve what pattern matching can do for us.

Why would I use pattern matching instead of this?

Comment: They are completely difference concepts. If you need a base class use it, if you need composition use it, if you need to switch on a type do so. If you are asking this question you probably need to read more of the documentation, there should be little cross over and should be used for what they do

Comment: I know but we can use them to achieve the same results and my question was about this, not about if they are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pattern matching plays a central role in functional programming just as polymorphism
plays a central role in object-oriented programming.

Besides that, I would personally use pattern matching whenever I know the full spectrum of possible types beforehand. E.g., a Maybe class which can either be a SomeValue or NoValue. For dynamic scenarios you can't use pattern matching in the first place.

To answer the original question: no, pattern matching is not better than polymorphism, it's something different.

Here is another great answer on the topic: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/231095